# How to reset a git repository including ignored files?

Tags: git

For this example, I made a structure like this:

```
touch ron .gitignore
echo generated-file > .gitignore
git init
git add . && git commit -m"Initial commit"
touch generated-file
echo modification > ron
touch untracked-file
git status --ignored=matching
```

So in my working tree, I have this `generated-file` file.
To "reset" my repository, I can remove the directory and clone the repository.

Is there a command that does the same?

I tried combinations of `git rm $(git status --ignored=matching)`.

Comment: You mean you want to remove every files including the ones ignored ?

Comment: Yes, like if "I remove the directory and clone the repository".

Comment: did you try `git clean -f -X ` sorry if I misunderstood something wrong.

Comment: @Ros5292 That's close! It does not remove the untracked and modified files tho.

Comment: but the document says it removes untracked files https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean

Comment: @Ros5292 it removes untracked files but not modified files

Comment: When using `git clean -f -x` it does remove untracked and ignored files :)
Using `git reset` is not a problem te remove the modified files, I can make a alias with both.

Comment: yeah I was suppose to suggest the same.

Comment: @Ros5292 can you make your comment an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+reset+ignored+files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git clean -f -X` is the best command for doing that. Fully explanation is here. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean. Ensure you dry run before running the command.

Comment: Thanks! I made an alias to catch all `git clean -f -x && git reset --hard`.